# javascript next number on multiples of three

Tags: javascript, arrays, math

I have a number for example `4`, i want to get next number on `multiples of 3`

Multiples of three: `[3,6,9,12,15,18,21,24,27,30,...]`

the result must be `6`

**i'm looking for a javascript function**

something like this:

```
function (myNum) { //myNum = 4;
    var multiples = [3,6,9,12,15,18,21,24,27,30];
    var result;
    // do something!!
    return result; // returns 6
}
```

thanks

Comment: What you have tried upto now in coding?

Comment: i did not write anything yet, but i think must by arrays

Comment: The goal of this site is to help you solve a problem in the code that you have already tried to write.  It is not for you to drop a specification and for us to write the code for you.  You need to show the code you have tried and explain where you got stuck.  If you want a hint, Google: "javascript array iteration".

Comment: @jfriend00 i have explained enough, and i did not know a solution

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a lot of ways you can achieve this. Here is an easy one. Increment the number until you get a multiple of three.

```
function multipleOfThree(num){
  while(num % 3 != 0)
    num++;
  return num;
}
```

Comment: yeah, this is the wise programmer, thanks ;-)

Answer (score 3):

I suggest another solution:

```js
function getNext(num, dep){
    return (((num % dep) ? dep:0) - num % dep) + num; 
}

document.write(getNext(4, 3));//6

//document.write(getNext(200, 7));//203
```

**Updated:** You can use this method for finding next number on multiples of any number

Comment: a complete solution ;-)

Answer (score 2):

You must try before asking a question. If you stuck at somewhere then it is good to ask questions with problem. By the way here what you can try:

```
function multiple(number) {
    return number % 3 === 0 ? ((number/3) * 3) : parseInt((number/3) + 1) * 3;
}
```

Comment: upvote because short solution, thanks ;)

Comment: So, you tell the OP they must try before asking a question, yet you just hand them an answer anyway?

Comment: Yes, If I know the answer, I always shares whether user had tried by self or not and after comment, Nabi has updated questions. I hope that in future that he will ask question after trying.

Comment: @SarjanDesai I search many times in google, but i did not found helpful solution